# How to generate some models for java with OpenApi Generator?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I successfully did generate a REST Client in java from a `Swagger/OpenApi v2.0` using `OpenApi Generator CLI 3.3.2-SNAPSHOT`

But I already have a REST Client, so I just want to generate some models from the spec.

I get success when I run:

```
java -Dmodels -DmodelDocs=false \
     -jar modules/openapi-generator-cli/target/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
     -i swagger.json \
     -g java \
     -o /temp/my_models
```

But when I want to generate just specific models with

```
java -Dmodels=Body,Header -DmodelDocs=false \
     -jar modules/openapi-generator-cli/target/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
     -i swagger.json \
     -g java 
     -o /temp/my_selected_models
```

I'm getting this ERROR:

> [main] INFO  o.o.c.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen - Environment
>   variable JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Java code may not
>   be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export
>   JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)

What is this JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE and how can I specify a valid format to generate the models?

Why the code generation success with all models but fails with a subset?

Answer (score 4):

That message is just informational. It aims to inform you that there's a way to auto-format the auto-generated Java code by specifying an environment variable with the auto code formatter (clang_format in this case):

```
export JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"
```

In other words, it does not affect the code generation process if the environment variable is not specified.

Comment: Oh! let me explain the situation: I know the message is informational, but it doesn't generate the files. That's the real problem, and that's the only message I'm getting, no errors, no files.

Comment: Please open an issue with details via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new if you've not done so.